# Multiple criteria search Query builder [symfony2]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have created a search form,i'm trying to fetch the following data from the database (`airport`,`airport1`,`departuredate`,`price`),i can only get [`airport`] but not the other entity.

This is my **controller**:

```
public function searchtabflightResultAction(Request $request)
{


    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchflightType());

    if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->searchflight($form['airport']->getData());

    } else {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('The page you were looking for doesn\'t exist.');
    }

    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:searchtabflightResult.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
}
```

**PostRepository.php**

```
public function searchflight($entity)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u')
            ->where('u.airport like :entity')
            ->andWhere('u.airport1 like :entity')
            ->orderBy('u.id')
            ->setParameter('entity', '%'.$entity.'%');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

**In your controller:**

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->searchflight($form);
```

**In your repo:**

```
public function searchflight(FormInterface $form)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    if ($form->has('airport')) {
        $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->like('u.airport', ':airport')
        )
           ->setParameter('airport', '%'. $form->get('airport')->getData().'%')
    }

    // ... complete like this with the other params
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried with your query, it work fine with price entity but when i'm looking for airport it doesn't find any result, i think is because is too strict.  With my query builder  i did it like this `'%'.$entity.'%'`. How can i make it to not be strict ?